# Server 2012 Modifying sharing privileges on a folder via script

Tags: permissions, batch, automation, windows-server-2012, shared-folders

I have recently been employed by a small company as a software engineer.  I am stepping a bit out of my element and doing a bit of IT work for them as needed as well.  Currently I am going over some of their disaster recovery methods and I am being asked to find spots that could be automated by scripting, preferably batch files.  So to the question at hand!

I have a folder:

`C:\SomeFolder`

I need to take the following actions on this folder:

- Navigate to the `C:\SomeFolder` folder
- Right click and select Properties
- Click the Sharing Tab
- Click Advanced Sharing
- Tick Share this folder
- Click on Permissions
  – Click Add…
- In the box enter “Users”
- Check Names (the Users name will become underlined if found)
- Click OK
- Check full control f.
- Remove the 'Everyone' Group
- Click OK

I would like to automate this task.  I have looked at net share and icacls I am not sure either of those are for this particular task, and as I am quite green (and learning) in this area I was hoping to get some advice.

Thanks in advance

JD

Comment: You were correct, net share and icacls are the things to use.

Comment: @MarkAllen as far as I can tell when I am using icacls it's only making modifications to folder permissions, not sharing.  When I've tried it using net share the folder has indeed become shared, but when you do the following Right Click the folder -> Properties -> Share -> Advanced Sharing -> Permissions it shows no change to what should be the affected sharing permissions.  Can you perhaps expand upon the process?

Comment: sorry, habit - I've run into main occasions where you share the folder with net share and then someone cannot access something because the NTFS permissions need to be adjusted. So you're right icacls doesn't alter the share permissions, it's just that you sometimes need to alter the NTFS permissions at the same time.

Comment: I see, I will keep that in mind as I go forward in this endeavor, thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was as follows:

```
@echo off
cls
mkdir C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test
net share testcase="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test" /UNLIMITED /grant:Administrator,FULL /grant:Administrators,FULL
```

This by default removed the Everyone group from the advanced sharing permissions.
Added the Administrator User with Full permissions.
Added the Administrators group with Full permissions.

Thanks for the point in the correct direction @MarkAllen